# PHPExcel date without dash, slash or else

Tags: php, date, phpexcel

I use a excel template with cell-format in column L as "custom" -> ddmmyyyy

From php page I call PHPExcel object and fill as follow:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValueExplicit('L'.$i, $birthdate, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

(in a loop but that is of no importance for the issue). 
The value $birthdate contains dates with a dash. And that is exactly as I want it to be...almost...=>
When the cells have been written and I open the excel file, I see all dates are
displayed in this
 format: dd-mm-yyyy
However, the cell-format of each cell in column L in that file
 is still "custom" -> ddmmyyyy
So I would expect the cells to show as ddmmyyyy...

Why is it still showing the dashes although cellformat is ddmmyyyy ?

Furthermore...when I click behind the date in the value bar (that field behind fx), and
 then press ENTER, then all of a sudden, the cell displays the date as ddmmyyyy...
Why not on opening the file? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally found the solution...put the date to 00:00:00 UTC =>

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $birthdate);
$birthdate  = $date->format('d-m-Y')." 00:00:00";
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$timestamp = strtotime($birthdate);
$dateValue = $timestamp;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)
        ->setCellValue('L'.$i, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($dateValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not storing the date as an Excel DateTime stamp, but as a string.

To store dates in MS Excel, you need to store the serialized timestamp value as shown in the examples

As shown in `/Examples/02types.php`

```
$dateTimeNow = time();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('C9', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($dateTimeNow));
```

The `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` will convert a unix timestamp, a PHP DateTime object, or most of the string formatted date values that `strtotime()` can handle to an MS Excel serialized timestamp

**EDIT**

You may need to do some manipulation of your `ddmmyyyy` format to a format that can easily be converted to a DateTime object:

```
$dateTimeValue = DateTime::createFromFormat('dMY', '18082015', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('C9', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($dateTimeValue));
```

Comment: I have nothing more to say Mark.... excellent!!! You just saved my day! :-) Thanks!